# Evernote API suddenly got very slow

Tags: php, sdk, evernote

The API Calls made by the PHP SDK started to get very slow since the 12th of April 2021 (more or less).

Any action that uses the `userStore` takes a long time. I did some test and sometime the `getUser()` method could take 3 - 4 seconds before getting a response.

Is there something we can do? or is it on Evernote's Server side?